# How to properly load StandardScaler to Tensorflow Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i have a problem about load StandardScaler to my tensorflow model.
I used the following code to load the StandardScaler model :

```
scaler_load = pickle.load(open(path + save_dir +'std_scaler_1.pkl', 'rb'))
X_test_load = scaler_load.transform(X_test_fs)
X_test_load
```

But when i load the model from disk and compile it with this code :

```
load_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path + save_dir + 'mlp_model_fs_25_1.h5')
load_model.compile(loss=[tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()], 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), 
              metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])
load_model.evaluate(X_test_load, y_test)
```

The results are different from when I did the first training and testing. When the first time, the results are as follows:

```
54/54 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1129 - accuracy: 0.9662 - mean_squared_error: 0.0294
[0.11291049420833588, 0.9661807417869568, 0.02943398430943489]
```

But when i load it the score is look like this

```
54/54 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.4714 - accuracy: 0.8583 - mean_squared_error: 0.1088
[0.47135162353515625, 0.8583090305328369, 0.10878879576921463]
```

Comment: First, try this checks. When you have trained your model in your disk, ask to the scaled object: `scaler.mean_` and `scaler.scale_`. Then, in the other program, load scaler_load as you have done, and ask the same: `scaler_load.mean_` and `scaler_load.scale_`.  These are the parameters that the object uses to scale. If your results are the same, then the problem is not in the StandarScaler. If they are different, please show the code how you have saved your object,.

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat does it affect when i do train_test_split with "Shuffle=True" enabled or not? Because when the runtime is terminate i'm running train test split again to get X_test, after that i passed to scaler_load and load_model

Comment: Yes, it affects to model accuracy. Why? Basically because you will be obtaining accuracies for different test sets. Before asking the accuracy, you should check that bot test_set are identical. Fix the parameter `random_state` to value to have always the same split. Anyway, I would recommend you try it and see results.

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat I've tried doing a train_test_split using the same random_state which is 42. And the result when I restart the runtime, take the value of X_test, load scaler and model the result is exactly the same. Is this correct or not in practice? 
Because i still confuse should i shuffle the datasets through train_test_split or not? And i need to load scaler and load model to real application

Comment: Depending on your purpose... What you want exactly? Just check if your models has same accuracy after loading? or deploy it?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat Yes i just want to check my model accuracy after deploy it